# Double quote in MySQL (Laravel Seeder)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a trouble with Laravel DB Seeder. I've tried to put value to json row:

> 'rating' => '{"avg":2,"clean":2,"place":1,"keeper":1}'

And I got this in MySQL:

```
"{\"avg\":2,\"clean\":2,\"place\":1,\"keeper\":1}"
```

But there is no problem with creating json array:

```
[{"number":"+7 999 9999999","name":"Some name"},{"number":"8 111 1234567","name":"Body"}]
```

Sorry for my English. Please, help!

**Update:** full seeder code

```
class ObjectTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        \App\Object::create([
            'category_id' => '2',
            'owner_id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Some name"',
            'rating' => '{"avg":2,"clean":2,"place":1,"keeper":1}',
            'phones' => '[{"number":"+7 999 9999999","name":"Some name"},{"number":"8 111 1234567","name":"Body"}]',
            'status' => '1'
    ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you like to show us some code that you use to store this data

Comment: Would you now like to add that to your question using the edit. As nobody can read code in a comment

Comment: sorry, done ...

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting while storing the phones field array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply change

```
'rating' => '{"avg":2,"clean":2,"place":1,"keeper":1}'
```

to array like this

```
'rating' => ["avg" => 2, "clean" => 2, "place" => 1, "keeper" => 1]
```

then in the **Object** model you cast that field into an array like this

```
protected $casts = [
    'rating' => 'array',
];
```

So anytime you are saving rating into the database laravel will serialize it and when retrieving it will deserialize it into an array

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about my casts and it provides double serialization.